# Revert customized View of Sharepoint List

Tags: list, sharepoint, office365, sharepoint-online

I'm using Office365 for Business.  I have a list created with various columns of data in them.  Everything was going well, and both View and Edit were usable.

I thought I could "jazz it up" a bit, so I hit "Customize" in the edit window while one of the items was open.  Brought me to PowerApps, etc.  Looked around, didn't change anything, and exited.

Now my edit and view windows are garbage.  I don't want to go in and build a custom view to make it work like it used to (Choice boxes and people selectors don't work properly.  An imported email body isn't displaying properly, etc.)  I need to get back to the default view and edit display.  I went into PowerApps and deleted everything, but it still uses the custom display.

How can I get a SharePoint list (I'm only using SharePoint online) to revert back to the non-customized display for view and edit?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to:

1. go to the `Site Contents` of your web
2. open your lists actions context menu with [image] button
3. click `Settings`
4. In list settings go to `Form settings` or something similar (i dont have english tenant)
5. choose first option to use default SharePoint form

Comment: Worked perfectly.  Thanks!